# Is the LOTRO data available?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I played Eve for a while and the community produced a lot of tools based on the data that CCP released to the public.

The data included stats on ships, modules, mobs, skills, etc. And players created all kinds of tools to help with planning your ship loadouts and your learning plan.

Is there a similar resource for Lord of the Rings Online?

I realize LOTRO is more role-playing oriented, meaning that people should spend less time tweaking and more time taking part in the community. It would also contain quite a bit of spoilers for the people who like to be surprised with new items. So I can understand if Turbine won't release any of the data.

But are there any reliable sources for this data besides Turbine themselves then?

The data has to be structured (in a relational database or XML or any other usable structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the US-Servers there is a webservice available but it's limited to characters, guilds and items of the character. Please have a look onto:

http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Data.lotro.com_Usage_Guide

Comment: The URL died :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also build plugins using Lua now too.  There are definitely limitations with the Lua User Interface API, but you could write a plugin to capture player events like changing stances and things like that.  I think the logging might be a little handicapped, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: LIMITED? You mean the same Lua that allows you to completely change the UI? How "free" do you want?

Comment: What free are you talking about? Have you used the Lua API for LOTRO? There are HUGE limitations in what is available to you, and what actions you can perform.  It is to prevent people from scripting everything.

Comment: er.. i was copying from the forums :)